# Sims 3 Steam release changes monitor colors slightly when full screen

Tags: technical-issues, linux, windows, the-sims-3

When I launch The Sims 3 on Windows via Steam, the colors are brightened when you press shift+tab to bring up the steam overlay. Conversely, on Linux (specifically, Ubuntu and derivatives, with Valve's Proton 4.11) this behavior is reversed - the game is darker, but the Steam overlay is normal.

On Linux, this color issue is fixed by playing in windowed mode, but I dislike playing in windowed. Is there some fix for full screen colors on Linux?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with [gamma correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction). If the game has an option like "use desktop gamma", try to enable it.